# how to program RadioGroup in the ListView on Android

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, radio-group, custom-adapter

I have a problem with the handle RadioGrup. The application gets the string from the OCR, which is cut and thrown into the adapter on the list of listview with 4 RadioButtons and it is already running.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/158361/screenshot-1336249818620.png

As shown in the screenshot are 4 EditText to which I return an item within a list according to which radiobuton was pressed.
How to send the string after selecting raiobutton?

My code:

```
public class ocrResults extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public static final int CAPTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public ListaAdapterResults listaAdapterRes;
public ListView id_list_tokens;     
public String[] splittedArray;
String tag = "Events";

public EditText etNazwa;
public EditText etAdres;
public EditText etGodziny;
public EditText etTelefon;
public RadioGroup radioGroup;

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      RadioSelect rs = new RadioSelect();
      rs.setItem(etNazwa.getText().toString());
      rs.setItem(etAdres.getText().toString());
      rs.setItem(etGodziny.getText().toString());
      rs.setItem(etTelefon.getText().toString());

      radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.group);

      switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
       case R.id.rbName:
           rs.setType("rbName");
           //etNazwa.setText(splittedArray[pos]);
           break;
       case R.id.rbAdres:
           rs.setType("rbAdres");
           break;
       case R.id.rbGodziny:
           rs.setType("rbGodziny");
           break;
       case R.id.rbTelefon:
           rs.setType("rbTelefon");
           break;
      }
      etNazwa.setText("");
      etAdres.setText("");
      etGodziny.setText("");
      etTelefon.setText("");
      radioGroup.clearCheck();
      Log.d(tag," potwierdz");
  }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.ocrresultsactivity);
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

   id_list_tokens = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.id_list_tokens);
   etNazwa  =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtResNazwa);
   etAdres  =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtResAdres);
   etGodziny=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtResGodziny);
   etTelefon=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtResTelefon);

   View btn_Zatw1 = findViewById(R.id.btnZatw1);
    btn_Zatw1.setOnClickListener(onSave);//this
   View btn_OCRmake1 = findViewById(R.id.btnOCRmake1);
    btn_OCRmake1.setOnClickListener(this);
   View btn_backtomain1 = findViewById(R.id.btnbacktomain1);
    btn_backtomain1.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()){
     case R.id.btnOCRmake1:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ocrResults.this, CaptureActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, CAPTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        break;
     case R.id.btnbacktomain1:
        startActivity(new Intent(ocrResults.this, and4ph.class));
        finish();
        break;
  }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (CAPTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
            String response = data.getStringExtra(edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.RESPONSE);
            insertResponse(response);
        }
   }
    }
    private void insertResponse(String response) {
    String strResult = response;
    splittedArray = strResult.split(" ");   //(strResult, ' ');
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    initListViewResp();
    }
    void initListViewResp() {           //Inicjalizacja ListView
    listaAdapterRes = new ListaAdapterResults(this, splittedArray);
    id_list_tokens.setAdapter(listaAdapterRes);

    //      if (mbutton[0] == true) { 
    //      mbutton[0]=holder.rb_Name;
    //       } else {
    //             // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the ImageView.
    //             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    //             holder.dealImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    //             dealImage = holder.dealImage;
    //         }


    id_list_tokens.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), splittedArray[pos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    updateListView();
}
private void updateListView() {
    listaAdapterRes.notifyDataSetChanged();
}    
    }
```

And my adapter:

```
public class ListaAdapterResults extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    String tag = "Events";
    private Activity context;
    private String[] splittedArray;

    public ListaAdapterResults(Activity context, String[] splittedArray){
        super(context, R.layout.wiersz_tokenu, splittedArray);
        this.context        = context;
        this.splittedArray  = splittedArray;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView     tv_Token;
        private RadioButton rb_Name;
        private RadioButton rb_Adres;
        private RadioButton rb_Godziny;
        private RadioButton rb_Telefon;
        private RadioGroup rgroup;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(tag," 3");
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder= null;
        RadioButton[] mbutton = null;

        if(rowView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.wiersz_tokenu, parent, false);
          holder = new ViewHolder();
          holder.rgroup     = (RadioGroup) rowView.findViewById(R.id.group);
          holder.tv_Token   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvToken);

          holder.rb_Name    = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rbName);
          holder.rb_Adres   = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rbAdres);
          holder.rb_Godziny = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rbGodziny);
          holder.rb_Telefon = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rbTelefon);

          mbutton=new RadioButton[4];
            mbutton[0]=holder.rb_Name;
            mbutton[1]=holder.rb_Adres;
            mbutton[2]=holder.rb_Godziny;
            mbutton[3]=holder.rb_Telefon;

          for(int i=0;  i<4; i++) {
              mbutton[i]=new RadioButton(context);
              //mbutton[l].setText("test"+l);
              //holder.rgroup.addView(mbutton[i]);
          }

          holder.rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
               public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup, int checkedId) {

                   for(int i=0; i<mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {

                       RadioButton rbtn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                       //int t=table.indexOfChild(table_row);   //System.out.println(t);

                       int t = mRadioGroup.getId();
                       System.out.println(t);

                       if(rbtn.getId() == checkedId) {
                           String text = rbtn.getText().toString();
                           // do something with text
                           //etNazwa.setText(text);

                           RadioSelect rs = new RadioSelect();
//                        rs.setItem(etNazwa.getText().toString());
//                        rs.setItem(etAdres.getText().toString());
//                        rs.setItem(etGodziny.getText().toString());
//                        rs.setItem(etTelefon.getText().toString());
//                        mRadioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroupTypET);

                          switch (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                           case R.id.rbName:
                               rs.setType("rbName");
                                     //String text = rbtn.getText().toString();
                                     //etNazwa.setText(text);
                               break;
                           case R.id.rbAdres:
                               rs.setType("rbAdres");
                               break;
                           case R.id.rbGodziny:
                               rs.setType("rbGodziny");
                               break;
                           case R.id.rbTelefon:
                               rs.setType("rbTelefon");
                               break;
                          }
                          Log.d(text," radioButtonSelect");
                          return;
                        }
                    }
                }
          });
          rowView.setTag(holder);
          Log.d(tag,"me");
       } else {
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
//        mbutton = holder.rgroup;
          Log.d(tag,"meeee");
       }
       ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
       holder1.tv_Token.setText(splittedArray[position]);
       Log.d(tag," event7");

       holder.tv_Token.setText(splittedArray[position]);
       holder.rb_Name.setTag(new Integer(position));
       holder.rb_Adres.setTag(new Integer(position));
       holder.rb_Godziny.setTag(new Integer(position));
       holder.rb_Telefon.setTag(new Integer(position));
//      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rgroup,int checkedId){  }
      return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getView method in `holder.rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener` set value for editText. 
e.g.

```
  String text = rbtn.getText().toString();
     etNazwa.setText(text);
```

It looks that you have this code commented but with wrong parameter. You have `etNazwa.setText(response);` and it should be  `etNazwa.setText(text);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but etNazwa.setText (text); is wrong because etNazwa it is one of four EditText of the first class that uses an adapter. And is it etNazwa.setText (text) should not be in the switch? I cleaned the adapter code.

Comment: Put your adapter class into your activity class and you should be able edit etNazwa text.

Comment: Only the adapter or just combine these two classes? I try to combine but now I have problem to use this adapter.

Comment: Use this structure class Activityclass extends Activity{ class adapterclass extends adapter{ getview(){ here you can set value for field defined in activityclass}   }}

Comment: Thank you, now it works. Just to copy as you write an adapter class below and removed the Public.